# Problem with Mongoose Model.find() method which is broken on production environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have problem with `Model.find()` mongoose method.On development environment it works properly but when I deployed my app on `heroku` and `mLab` it doesn't work properly.In my project I have search menu with drop down list of items which are coming from database and I pass them to handlebars template .When click on the dropdown there are items from which you can choose :[link](http://s1356.photobucket.com/user/acho999/media/dev-env_zpslcfsyvmc.jpg.html)

But when i go to production doesn't work:http://s1356.photobucket.com/user/acho999/media/production%20-evironment_zpsb49om1nz.png.html

My js file have down code.And I do not know where I am wrong.I read a lot of articles.I disabled autoindex in my models schema, i read about mongodb driver i update it, also compatability of `MongoDb` and Mongoose, they are last resions...
I have no idea what is wrong.Please help me with this.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Condition = require("../models/Condition");
const Manufacturer = require("../models/Manufacturer");
const Material = require("../models/Material");
const Kind = require("../models/Kind");
const Type = require("../models/Type");
const db = require("../connection/databaseConn");

router.get("/categoriesLoad",(req,res)=>{

        let types = [];
        let kinds = [];
        let materials = [];
        let conditions = [];
        let manufacturers = [];

    //db.then(()=>{
        
        Type.find({},(err,t)=>{
            t.forEach(x=>types.push(x));
        });

        Kind.find({},(err,t)=>{
            t.forEach(x=>kinds.push(x));
        });

        Material.find({},(err,t)=>{
            t.forEach(x=>materials.push(x));
        });

        Condition.find({},(err,t)=>{
            t.forEach(x=>conditions.push(x));
        });

        Manufacturer.find({},(err,t)=>{
            t.forEach(x=>manufacturers.push(x));
        }).then(()=>{
            
            let add = req.session.addMessage;
    
            req.session.addMessage ="";
            
            res.render("adminArea",{types,kinds,materials,conditions,manufacturers,add});
        });
    
    //})
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things to look at :

is your database filled with objects.
is your code synchronous buid.

manufacturer will execute the .then maybe befor everything else is even done.
all those .find()'s will execute at the same time so if manafacturer is done it will execute .then() and then you get empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is that you cannot ensure `Manufacturer.find` will finish after all the other database queries are completed.

Another problem is, never mix callbacks and Promises, try to unify the coding style, while callbacks are so ES5, I suggest using Promise only.

Try this:

```
Promise.all([
  Type.find().exec(),
  Kind.find().exec(),
  Material.find().exec(),
  Condition.find().exec(),
  Manufacturer.find().exec()
]).then(([types, kinds, materials, conditions, manufacturers]) => {
  const add = req.session.addMessage;
  req.session.addMessage = '';
  res.render('adminArea', {
    types,
    kinds,
    materials,
    conditions,
    manufacturers,
    add
  });
});
```